# call http get in jasmine and not get a timeout

Tags: typescript, testing, jasmine

I am mocking my `http.get` but still get a timeout in my test.

> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

I have done everything I can think of and read about. The `done` method, `HttpClientTestingModule`, I have event tried `flush`-ing the `expectOne` result but to no avail.

In the console I see the 'testee.res' result
but I *don't* se the 'tester.result'.

---

#### Testee:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MetadataService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }


  public myMethod(): Observable<string> {
    const res = this.http.get<string>('myurl');
    
    console.log('testee.res',res);
    return res;
  }
}
```

#### Tester:

```
describe('MetadataService', () => {
  let service: MetadataService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HttpClientTestingModule,
        },
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(MetadataService);
  });

  it('should call http get', (done) => {
    const http = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

    //  Act.
    service.myMethod().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('tester:result',result);
      
      //  Assert.
      http.expectOne('myurl');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClientModule` should be removed. It didn't change the test outcome; but it makes me wonder what is injected as `HttpClient` in the testee. The reason I had it is because it has, in earlier tests, been required due to reasons unknown to me.

Remove `done()`. I understand that it is not necessary any more but I don't know why keeping it kept the timeout error. I believe(d) it just sets a flag for Jasmine to check for that the test is finished. And as I called `done` in the `subscribe` block the flag should be set. But I guess it is more complex than that.
*Does anyone know?*

The `expectOne` had to be moved to outside and after the `subscribe` call.
The reason is that `http.get` does not return anything before `http.expectOne` is called. Having the `expectOne` call inside the `subscribe` made the `subscribe` block never run since `get` didn't return. Hence the timeout.

```
describe('MetadataService', () => {
  let service: MetadataService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HttpClientTestingModule,
        },
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(MetadataService);
  });

  it('should call http get', () => {
    const http = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

    //  Act.
    service.myMethod().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('tester:result',result);
    });

    //  Assert.
    http.expectOne('myurl');
  });
});
```